# Do I still need to configure TLS/SSL for all NGINX ingress beneath an AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a set of nginx ingresses exposed via an nginx NodePort service to a singular AWS ALB ingress controller. The request comes in via ALB and ALB sends it to the NGINX service that reaches out to the appropriate backend service according to the set rules.

Now I want to setup TLS/SSL (HTTPS) for my cluster. Do I just set one up for the ALB or for each of the nginx ingresses.

Comment: Is it your intention to offload SSL to the load balancer?

Comment: Yes. If possible @jarmod

Comment: OK, so just configure TLS on the load balancer per the documentation. Note that this means TLS will be terminated on the LB and traffic between the LB and your web servers will not be TLS. That's probably the most common configuration, but if you absolutely want traffic to EC2 to be encrypted, then you need to configure HTTPS from ALB to EC2 (again, see docs).